# Inequality with supremum of a specific integral

Tags: integration, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I'm reading Kai Diethelm's "The analysis of fractional differential equations" and there's a part I haven't been able to figure out. It's from page 93.

Let $p >0.$ Why does the following inequality hold?

$\frac{L}{\Gamma(p)}\sup_{0\leq w \leq x}\int_{0}^{w}(w-t)^{p-1}|A^{j-1}y_{1}(t)-A^{j-1}y_{2}(t)|dt\\
    \leq \frac{L}{\Gamma(p)}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^{p-1}\sup_{0\leq w \leq t}|A^{j-1}y_{1}(w)-A^{j-1}y_{2}(w)|dt$

Comment: I am not familiar with fractional differential equations, but it seem to me that more information is needed. What are $L, A, y_1, y_2$? Is $\Gamma$ the Gamma-function or something else?

Comment: $(Ay)(x)=T(x)+\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^{p-1}f(t, y(t))dt$
$\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. L is some constant.
$y_1, y_2\in C[0,h]$ where h is some positive real number. $T(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}y^{(k)}_{0}$. $m=\lceil p \rceil$. f is a continuous function.